# Why is there no wildlife on Alpha Halo (Halo: CE)?

Tags: halo

It seems pretty obvious that Halo rings are suitable for wildlife. Zeta Halo (Halo from Halo Infinite) is inhabited by a huge amount of wild species. Also, we see wildlife in Halo 2 and 3.

So why Alpha Halo is so empty, like there is no wildlife at all?

Comment: I know that Xbox had limited capabilities, but what is a cannon explanation?

Comment: The out of universe explanation is that Bungie thought wildlife diminished the Flood reveal. Several animal were made and later cut.

Comment: @nolimon - back that up with evidence and you've got yourself a pretty solid answer to post

Comment: A lot of the levels are set in active warzones, internal tunnels and bits of the ring infested by Flood. Perhaps unsurprising that the wildlife is lying low!

Comment: @SeanCondon well, if they are staying low, why they are not shown as combat/infected forms after Flood outbreak? Plus, from terminals we know that ring was empty from the begging, but why? If it applies for any Halo ring, then why Zeta Halo is sprawled with wildlife?

Comment: The Flood killed them all

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is actually a small amount of wildlife on Alpha Halo (Installation 04) in *Halo: Combat Evolved*:

- [Moths](https://www.halopedia.org/Moth) are found in the swamps on the level *343 Guilty Spark*
- Small [worms](https://www.halopedia.org/Sea_worm) are found in the sea on the level *Silent Cartographer* (only in the original game, not in *Halo: Combat Evolved Anniversary*)

In addition, sounds from other creatures can be heard throughout the game, such as owl-like bird calls and cricket-like insect sounds.

However, according to an old news story on Bungie.net, [One Million Years B.X. (Before Xbox)](https://web.archive.org/web/20041011112259/http://www.bungie.net/News/TopStory.aspx?story=prexboxhistory040904), now only found in the Wayback Machine, more prominent wildlife was also originally planned, but scrapped mostly for technical reasons:

> **The Fauna of Halo**
>
> The main reasons that the Fauna, a collection of pseudo-dinosaurs and herds of vaguely mammalian varmints) were dropped from Halo (and relatively far into the process) were the usual combination of time constraints, design issues and performance problems. But another, perhaps more fundamental philosophical reason was that the inclusion of another set of inhabitants of Halo would have detracted from the surprise, drama and impact of the Flood.
>
> Problems with AI for the creatures, problems with how they would react and behave during action sequences and even things like basic herd mentality meant that more important features (like vehicles and finishing the game on time) had to take precedence.
>
> Although a populated Halo ring is unarguably cool, the sense of abandonment and mystery is actually heightened without them. The deserted landscapes and eerily empty structures actually serve to enhance the mystery of the Forerunners. But that's an accident of design rather than a purpose.
>
> The sad thing is that the assets created for the animals, the animation, models and textures, were all largely complete. But those dinosaurs were destined never to roam the ring. Unless Bungie one day decided to make a dinosaur racing game!

Comment: Apologies for the wiki source links, it's hard to find other good sources for this. Feel free to edit my answer with better ones, perhaps YouTube videos?

Answer (score 3):

Installation 04 or "Alpha Halo" was built over 100,000 years prior events Halo 1. As such some small insect/arthropod lifeforms were on the ring, but complex animals were devoid.

According the Terminal 4 briefing, the Smart AI 343 Guilty Spark eventually found himself bored and for his own entertainment, began an experiment in which he evacuated entire sections of the Installation into space and reunited them. Likely this killed all complex animals and fauna aboard.

> *"For amusement I have begun a series of experiments involving the
> evacuation of all matter from contained sections of my installation.
> By measuring the geological effects of exposure to the vacuum of space
> and the eventual biological recovery of these sessions, I anticipate
> getting valuable insight into emergency response scenarios."*